# Angular - Response is not assignable to type 'request?: HttpRequest<any>

Tags: angular, typescript, auth-guard

I try to write an AuthGuard in Angular but i get the following Error:

> Type 'typeof AuthServiceService' is not assignable to type '(request?: HttpRequest) => string | Promise'.
> Type 'typeof AuthServiceService' provides no match for the signature '(request?: HttpRequest): string

This is my auth-service.service.ts:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthServiceService {

  constructor(
    private http:HttpClient,
    public jwtHelper: JwtHelperService) { }
  login(data):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(baseUrl + 'ApplicationUser/login' ,data)

  }

  handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    return throwError(error);
  }

  public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    return !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token);
  }

}
```

Here is my AuthGuard Service:

```
import { AuthServiceService } from 'src/services/auth/auth/auth-service.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(public auth: AuthServiceService, public router: Router) { }
  
  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (!this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      this.router.navigate(['']);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

I get this error on this line on tokenGetter:

```
const JWT_Module_Options: JwtModuleOptions = {
  config: {
    tokenGetter: AuthServiceService
  }
};
```

Can somebody help me what the response from AuthService should look like?

Comment: `Observables` only fire when they have a subscriber. Instead of returning from the constructor (?) add a `subscribe` block where you do your work (presumably, set the auth token in `localStorage`.

Comment: how you are defining the AuthGuard component..? it gives good idea about your issue if you added that code too..

Comment: where you are getting the above compilation error, can you show that as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research i have found the solution.
The tokenGetter Option needs a string with my token - so i returned the token from the local storage like below:

```
const JWT_Module_Options: JwtModuleOptions = {
  config: {
    tokenGetter: () => {
      return localStorage.getItem('token')
    }
  }
};
```

Now my AuthGuard works as expected :)
Thank you all for help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine (at least for me) except one issue is that initializing method inside of the `constructor`

```
 constructor(private http:HttpClient,
    public jwtHelper: JwtHelperService) { }
  login(data):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(baseUrl + 'ApplicationUser/login' ,data)

  }
```

change this to below

```
  constructor(private http:HttpClient, public jwtHelper: JwtHelperService) { }
    
  login(data): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.post(baseUrl + 'ApplicationUser/login' ,data)
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! i formatted my code as you suggested. But sadly this was not the solution.

Comment: I have edit my post with the code where i get the error: 
const JWT_Module_Options: JwtModuleOptions = {
  config: {
    tokenGetter: AuthServiceService
  }
};

Comment: then it's clearly saying pre-defined `JwtModuleOptions` class param `tokenGetter` expecting the `HttpRequest` as param. did you tried this one..